# Query rows with common value over result set partition

Tags: postgresql

I'm on Postgres 11 and I have these tables

```
 foo              foobar

| id |      | foo_id | bar_id |
------      -------------------
|  a |      |      a |      1 |
|  b |      |      a |      2 |
|  c |      |      b |      2 |
|  d |      |      b |      3 |
```

And I need all `bar_id` which are common to all `foo`s. So I have this query:

```
select b.bar_id from foo f join foobar b on b.foo_id = f.id
```

which gives me

```
1
2
2
3
```

while I'd need just `2`, i.e. the intersection of the result set partitioned by `f.id`. Then, I might apply a `where` clause, e.g. `where f.id in (...)`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There isn't a foobar ('c',2) and ('d',2)

Comment: What do you mean `"all bar_id which are common to all foo"`? Your sample data has no rows of `foobar` common for all `foo` - `c` and `d` aint represented in the `foobar`

Comment: I oversimplified my example, I'll prepare a more real one!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your desired result do not use all `foo` values, there is no ('c',2) and ('d',2), then you can remove it from the equation and use only `foobar` table.

```
select
    barid
from
    foobar
group by 
    barid
having 
    count(fooid) = (select count(distinct fooid) from foobar);
```

> ```
> | barid |
> | ----: |
> |     2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e6000fc677591bd6f2e663ee0d17f62a)*

Comment: Thank you! The query comes from an ORM library which needs `foo` as the query root (maybe I oversimplified the example); neat trick with `having count`! Any higher level semantic to avoid the subquery comes to your mind? Also Postgres specific would work.

Comment: Why should `foo` be the query root? The problem is to find *"all **bar** ids which ..."*

Comment: For many other ways to accomplish this, see: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: Thank you @ypercubeᵀᴹ that answer lead me to the [For an unknown number of properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512013/1006669) which solves my issue similarly as McNets suggested but with the level of abstraction I need (i.e. without the group by on the main query).